# find polygon boundaries for a labelmap

Tags: matlab, svg, polygon

[image]

I have a labelmap matrix describing an image. As shown in the image, it is visualized in Matlab by

```
imshow(im,[])
```

How can I extract polygon boundaries describing each label region? For all  labels, I would have a set of polygon boundaries. What is the most efficient way of extract all these polygon boundaries?

Comment: "[B, L] = bwboundaries(BW, 'noholes');", this might help you. "B" contains values of the boundaries of all components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it simply with `imcontour` or `bwboundaries`. Here is an exemple:

```
% Get the values in your image
val = unique(im);

% Pre-allocate output
C = cell(numel(val),1);

% Here we go
for i = 1:numel(val)
    C{i} = bwboundaries(im==val(i));
end
```

The output `C` will be a cell of cells, containing the contours.

> NB: your original image looks like a raw conversion to a few levels of
>   gray. To reduce noise at the boundaries, you may want to consider
>   applying a median filter with `imfilter` and `filter`.